# String concatenation and @

Tags: c#, string

I have the following code which uses a string like this :

```
string str = @"this is very important string ,which uses hardcoded name";
```

I want to change it to have a value of input argument

```
public void func (string name)
{
    // some code
    string str = "this is very important string ,which uses " + name;
}
```

When I generate the string I still need to use "@" what can I do?

```
string str = @("this is very important string ,which uses " + name);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I still need to use "@" "? What errors are you getting?

Comment: string str = String.Format("this is very important string ,which uses{0}",name); is a better option to format string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `@` before every **string literal** (and only literals, not variables) if you want to treat escape sequences literally. So in your case, you only need to do:

```
string str = @"this is very important string ,which uses " + name;
```

BTW, using `@` for `"this is very important string ,which uses "` won't make a difference as it doesn't have any escape sequences.

More about [verbatim string literals on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim string literal may span multiple lines.

Thus an example where `@` makes a difference may be for the tab character `\t`:

```
string c = "hello \t world";    // hello     world <-- tab here
string d = @"hello \t world";   // hello \t world <-- treated literally
```